# Why are there some class files contained in the android-support-v4.jar but not in its source folder?

Tags: android, jar, android-support-library

In the android support library directory of Android SDK: `<SDK PATH>\extras\android\support\v4`, there is a file named `android-support-v4.jar` and a `src`folder.

When I decompile the jar file using Java Decompiler, I get some classes that do not exist in the src folder. For example the class `FragmentContainer` exists in the jar file but does not show up in the `src` folder.[image]

Why is that? I thought the `src` folder must contain all the source files of the `android-support-v4.jar` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably just an artifact of the decompilation. It seems like it's defined within FragmentManager.java, see [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2_r1/android/app/FragmentManager.java#FragmentContainer).